# Excluding a particular jar file from the shared library in weblogic

Tags: shared-libraries, dynamic-class-loaders

I have 2 modules one is the EAR file and another is static shared library. The static shared library is already deployed on a server .This static library is a collection of jar files deployed as a library(and NOT application) on weblogic.

Now I need to deploy the EAR application on server and this EAR app refers to the static library (via  reference in it's weblogic.xml)

The problem is both the EAR app and static library has a common jar and I want the jar from my EAR to be loaded(as it is higher version) but unfortunately Weblogic loads the jar coming from the shared library and not from the EAR file.

Is there any way I can tell the weblogic server in case of conflict with jar  within EAR and shared library, to exclude certain jar coming from the shared library and give the JAR (coming from EAR ) precedence over that coming from shared library?

I tried looking into the weblogic docs but didn't see a proper solution on instructing the WLS on class loading.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in your weblogic-application.xml

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Or you could have two shared libs and in your ear define which one your ear has to use it's also in the weblogic-application.xml

```
<library-ref>
    <library-name>NAME_OF_YOUR_LIB</library-name>
    <specification-version>VERSION_TO_USE</specification-version>
    <exact-match>false</exact-match>
</library-ref>
```